# resizing images for different desktop and mobile views

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a structure where there are only images like below for desktop view and mobile view with a fixed height respectively in both views.

[image: structure of images]

In mobile view images come out stretched.
I have applied a couple of solutions where images get cropped either from top, bottom, left and right and in my case i don't want. 
How should i proceed so that images do not stretch in any view?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want a fixed layout (as in your image), you can use `background-image`/`background-size` and set it like this

```
background: url(...) no-repeat;        /* the shorthand property */
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
```

The `cover` value make the image always fill the element without stretching it and with `background-position` you can control whether an image should be centered, left, right, bottom, top aligned

```css
div {  
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/300/400/animals/4) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
div ~ div {  
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
div ~ div ~ div {  
  height: 500px;
  width: 200px;
  background-position: left center;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

If you don't want to crop, you can use `background-size: contain` instead.

```css
div {  
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/300/400/animals/4) no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: left bottom;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
div ~ div {  
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
div ~ div ~ div {  
  height: 500px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Update based on comment, using percent height (relative to the body) on an `img`

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
img {  
  height: 40%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/400/animals/4" alt="">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/animals/4" alt="">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/4" alt="">
```

Comment: the first solution with background-size: cover is pretty good - only issue is it crops up the image.
Can't use contain because there will be some extra space shown.
Thanks for this, would you be having any other solution for this.

Comment: @pdjinn Then I'm not sure how you want, as either your crop, scale or stretch an image to fit a certain layout? .. If not, then you just give an `img` element a fixed height and set width to auto.

Comment: that's the way i had been doing it with a fixed height and width: 100% which stretches the image as my layout is responsive. Is there any solution i can apply using multiple images. width: auto will again show extra space

Comment: @pdjinn I updated my answer with a 3:rd sample, fully responsive relative to the height, no cropping or stretch.

Comment: @pdjinn If your images aren't an exact size of the layout structure, you can't do what you want without cropping, stretching or some empty space. Please update your question with a working sample of the images you have and I will be able to tell how it has to be.

Comment: @pdjinn When looking at your image showing the layout, there is no way that images fitting the desktop layout can fit the mobile as their aspect ratio is not the same, so a crop, stretch, or empty space is a must (if to keep the mobile layout of course).

Comment: You're perfectly right. so basically this wouldn't be possible as the width would always keep on changing as this is a responsive layout. i'll either have to crop or stretch the image. Thanks a lot for your help.
i'll update here if i find anything to optimize this